# Скажите пожалуйста название принта как нужно написать с большой или маленькой,и нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: запятые

Как правильно написать ч маленькой или нет,а кавычки нужны?

Comment: Очень странный вопрос. Можете его переформулировать или написать примеры?